# How to update PHP version

Tags: phpmyadmin, updates

This may seem a really silly question, but how do I update my PHP? I am using phpMyAdmin and it says 'Version information: 3.5.8.1'. I am also using Parallels Plesk and have checked that this is on PHP5.3 Support. But how do I actually update PHP to something higher than 3.5.8.1? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Version information: 3.5.8.1' - it is version of phpmyadmin but not php. What is your Plesk version? Latest Plesk 12.5 version has multiple PHP feature with support of PHP7. phpmyadmin also was updated recently in one of latest Plesk updates.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That's possibly where I was getting confused then. My Plesk shows that I am operating 'PHP version is 5.3.3' - which I believe is fairly recent? It also shows that my Plesk system is up to date.

Comment: Just go to Tools&Settings -> Updates and Upgrades and install needed PHP version or versions.